# Get invoked Progress procedure .p file location at runtime

Tags: file, procedure, openedge, progress-4gl

Lets say I have a simple procedure file in my system:

`C:\git\project\helloworld.p`

Inside this procedure file, the code needs to know it's location on my system at runtime. So in my computer in this case it would be:

`C:\git\project\helloworld.p`

In my friend's computer it could be:

`D:\codingprojects\project\helloworld.p`

**Is there any way to resolve the procedure file location at runtime?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
FILE-INFO:FILE-NAME = THIS-PROCEDURE:FILE-NAME.
MESSAGE FILE-INFO:FULL-PATHNAME.
```

Answer (score 1):

Why is the location relevant? Your code should **never** be using absolute paths, but only using:

`run helloworld.p`

Your working directory should be `c:\git\project` with a `propath` containing a `.` entry indicating look in the working directory.

Comment: You're right, we should not be using absolute paths.
This question is really used to find a way to use relative paths. I want to be able to define relative paths which are relative to the .p file's location.